# Maintain scroll position when write into input or textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a input text filed on top of my website.

If i keep the cursor into input field then i scroll down of my website and i write a character, the scroll go automatically in top where the input field is.

I would like the scroll not move (maintain `scrollTop`) when i write a character into input text field.

I have try a lot of solution but never work. Example:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
},100)


$(document).on("keypress blur paste change",".wmd-input",function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="100" placeholder="write here when you are in bottom of page"/>
<div style="width:100%;height:2000px;background:red">
</div>
```

Even with `setTimeout()` into `keypress` function not working.

```js
setInterval(function() {
    tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
},100)


$(document).on("keypress blur paste change",".wmd-input",function(){
  setTimeout(function() {  
      $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);
  },1000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="100" placeholder="write here when you are in bottom of page"/>
<div style="width:100%;height:2000px;background:red">
</div>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Well, this is an expected sensible behaviour of browsers. Why do you want this thing not to happen? If you want the textbox to be always visible, use `position: fixed`.

Comment: Yes i can, but in my case the input element can't be move because i create a small game with a difficulty. Is there a way to do this? thx

Comment: as @PraveenKumar said, this is default behavior of browsers. There is also a security implication: every user should be aware of what is being typed.

Comment: @P.Frank as I gave you a solution too. Why not use `position: fixed`?

Comment: Ok thx. I try with other way for make this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will not give you the complete solution you are looking for (because you still have the jumps in the scroll), but you can use the following code to move the user back to it's old position **after** the typing is done:

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var ignoreScroll = false;

$(document).on('scroll', function(e) {
  if (!ignoreScroll) {
    lastScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  }
});
$(document).on("keydown",".wmd-input",function(e){
  ignoreScroll = true;
  $(document).scrollTop(lastScrollTop);
});
$(document).on("keyup",".wmd-input",function(e){
  ignoreScroll = false
  $(document).scrollTop(lastScrollTop);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="100" class="wmd-input" placeholder="write here when you are in bottom of page"/>
<div style="width:100%;height:2000px;background:red">
1<br />
2<br />
3<br />
4<br />
5<br />
6<br />
7<br />
8<br />
9<br />
10<br />
11<br />
12<br />
13<br />
14<br />
15<br />
16<br />
17<br />
18<br />
19<br />
20<br />
21<br />
22<br />
23<br />
24<br />
25<br />
26<br />
27<br />
28<br />
29<br />
30<br />
31<br />
32<br />
33<br />
34<br />
35<br />
36<br />
37<br />
38<br />
39<br />
40<br />
41<br />
42<br />
43<br />
44<br />
45<br />
46<br />
47<br />
48<br />
49<br />
50<br />
51<br />
52<br />
53<br />
54<br />
55<br />
56<br />
57<br />
58<br />
59<br />
60<br />
61<br />
62<br />
63<br />
64<br />
65<br />
66<br />
67<br />
68<br />
69<br />
70<br />
71<br />
72<br />
73<br />
74<br />
75<br />
76<br />
77<br />
78<br />
79<br />
80<br />
81<br />
82<br />
83<br />
84<br />
85<br />
86<br />
87<br />
88<br />
89<br />
90<br />
91<br />
92<br />
93<br />
94<br />
95<br />
96<br />
97<br />
98<br />
99<br />
100<br />
</div>
```